# Ввод из консоли несколько раз, через цикл while

Tags: java

Я реализовал возможность добавления корней уравнения в консоль только один раз, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать ввод из консоли несколько раз, через цикл while

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        double a, b, c, D;

        System.out.println("Дано квадратное уравнение");
        System.out.println("ax^2 + bx + c = 0");
        System.out.println("Введите a, b и c:");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        a = in.nextDouble();
        b = in.nextDouble();
        c = in.nextDouble();

        D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        if (D > 0) {
            double x1, x2;
            x1 = (-b - Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b + Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println("Корни уравнения: x1 = " + x1 + ", x2 = " + x2);
        } else if (D == 0) {
            double x;
            x = -b / (2 * a);
            System.out.println("Уравнение имеет один корень: x = " + x);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Уравнение не имеет корней!");
        
        }
        }
```

Comment: 1. почитать про цикл while. 2. создать цикл. 3. перенести в него нужную часть кода. С чем из этого возникли проблемы?

Comment: и почему у вас заголовок об одном, а в вопрос совсем о другом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

самое простое как можно реализовать:

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = in.nextDouble();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        b = in.nextDouble();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        c = in.nextDouble();
```

если вы желаете через цикл то попробуйте так:

```
int i=1;
do{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
if(i==1)
{
a = in.nextDouble();
} 
if(i == 2)
{
 b = in.nextDouble();
}
if(i == 3)
{
 c = in.nextDouble();
}
i++;
 
}while(i < 3)
```

выглядит конечно не очень, но если вам принципиально через while то можете так.

Можете так же записать вводимые данные в массив и потом вызывать из массива определенные позиции где хранятся данные. Пример myArray[a,b,c]

```
double[] myArray = new int[2];
i=0;
do{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
myArray[i] = in.nextDouble();
i++;
}while(i!=3)

D = myArray[1] * myArray[1] - 4 * myArray[0] * myArray[2]; //D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
```